# Real Browser Metrics in eggPlant Performance tool

Tags: testing, performance-testing, eggplant

Our organization is in the need of executing Performance test in Protocol level(HTTP requests) and UI Level(Browser Actions).

After doing some explorations, I found that eggPlant has option to execute functional scripts in eggPlant Performance. Do any one know about what are all the Real Browser Metrics which eggPlant Performance is providing?

Looking forward for some useful helps.

Answer (score 0):

EggPlant Performance doesn't provide a fixed number of metrics. A better mental model is to understand that while a test suite is running EggPlant records *event log entries*. These event log entries are consumed by a collection of analysis tools to derive whatever charts and metrics are determined to be relevant. In addition to the default events captured during a test run EggPlant supports the logging of custom events.

This is useful because it allows you as the user to choose what metrics are relevant to your specific use case.

Instead of asking "What metrics are there?" a better question to be asking is "What metrics do I care about?".